# how to pass specific pattern in junit

Tags: java, gradle, junit, integration-testing

How I can pass the pattern to Junit for matching the class and running the tests. Currently, my classes end with `..IT.java` but Junit by default checks classes which have pattern `Test.java` or `Tests.java`. How can i run these test cases? I am using Gradle to build the project. when i am running the test i am getting output like this.

```
:ScbeIntegrationTest:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:ScbeIntegrationTest:processResources NO-SOURCE
:ScbeIntegrationTest:classes UP-TO-DATE
:ScbeIntegrationTest:compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
:ScbeIntegrationTest:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:ScbeIntegrationTest:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:ScbeIntegrationTest:test NO-SOURCE
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `IT.java` suffix is a convention used by the [Maven Failsafe Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/). All classes in the test directory that have the suffix IT are executed by this plugin in the `integragion-test` phase but for Gradle is different, you should use *`sourceSets`* for Gradle.

You can check the way to do that here: https://guides.gradle.org/migrating-from-maven/

The **summary steps** are something like this:

1. Create a new source set called integrationTest.
2. Ensure that the output of the main and test source sets is added to the compile time classpath.
3. Ensure that the output of the main and test source sets is added to
   the runtime classpath.
4. Set the source directory of your integration tests to
   src/integration-test/java.
5. Set the resource directory of your integration tests to
   src/integration-test/resources.
6. Create a new task called integrationTest and set its type to Test.
7. Configure the location of the compiled test classes.
8. Configure the classpath that is used when our integration tests are run.

Steps font: https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/gradle/getting-started-with-gradle-integration-testing/

Hope it help.